# Typescript error 'argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm relatively new to TS, and I'm running into a weird issue. I seem to have defined everything, but it doesn't seem to recognize my typing for the data.

Here is what I have:

```
const Component = () => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState([[], []])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    const fetchData = React.useCallback(async () => {
        const data = await fetchDataController()

        setData(data)
                ^^^^ error
    })
}
```

This throws the error,

```
Argument of type 'Element[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[][]>'
  Type 'Element[][]' is not assignable to type 'never[][]'
    Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'
      Type 'Element is not assignable to type 'never'
```

My function `fetchDataController` return an array of arrays of elements.

My type is as follows:

```
type TData = {
  id: string,
  desc: string
}
```

I've tried doing something like,

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState<Array<TData[], TData[]>>([[], []])
```

But that didn't seem to work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. `Array<...>` requires one argument, the type of items in the array. So you could do something like `Array<TData[]>`. If you don't want to use `Array<...>`, you could do something like `TData[][]` as well

So,

```js
React.useState<TData[][]>([[], []])
```

Here's a [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-wave-czvk8?file=/src/App.tsx) with some mocks

---

If you want to be more specific, and define it as a [Tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), instead of usual array:

```js
React.useState<[TData[], TData[]]>([[], []])
```

but for that to work, you'll have to assure Typescript that what you are setting i.e. `data` in `setData(data)` is also of type `[TData[], TData[]]`.

You can do that with something like `setData(data as [TData[], TData[]])`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was setting data without mentioning its structure (like `setData(data as [TData[], TData[]])`). Including that fix - my ts stopped failing :)